# Google charts "Row given with size different than" when data.addRows from var

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

im trying to create bar chart and   but for some reason,it dosnt work.

when i copy past data to  data.addRows method it working fine but when i insert the data to **var rawData**  im receiving

```
Row given with size different than 8 (the number of columns in the table).
```

**this is the code:**

```
    data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'a');
    data.addColumn('number', 'b');
    data.addColumn('number', 'c');
    data.addColumn('number', 'd');
    data.addColumn('number', 'e');
    data.addColumn('number', 'f');
    data.addColumn('number', 'g');
    data.addRows([[rawData]]);
```

and this is the value of **console.log(rawData);**

```
[8,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],[9,0,0,3,0,1,0,2],[10,0,0,20,0,1,0,7],[11,13,0,24,2,7,0,16],[12,0,1,23,2,3,0,1],[13,2,4,31,2,0,0,6],[14,0,0,53,0,2,0,4],[15,0,1,57,2,2,0,13],[16,0,0,46,0,7,0,6],[17,0,0,61,0,0,0,7],[18,0,0,15,3,2,0,3],[19,0,0,0,1,0,0,182],[21,0,2,0,0,0,0,305],[23,0,0,0,0,6,0,1]
```

thanks

miki

Comment: `rawData` appears to be a string, not an array, which is why you get that error message.  How are you creating `rawData`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rawData` is already defined as array of arrays so you have to call:

```
data.addRows(rawData);
```

instead of

```
data.addRows([[rawData]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

changing

`data.addRows([graphcontent[0]]);`

to

`data.addRows(graphcontent[0]);`

fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

rawData is already defined as array so you have to call:

`data.addRows([rawData]);`

It should not like  `data.addRows([[rawData]]);`  or  `data.addRows(rawData);`